# Llenar un DropDownList dependiendo de una consulta con condicional en asp.net mvc 5 entity framework

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework, controller, dropdownlist

Hola tengo que llenar un  dropdownlist con los datos que me arroje esta consulta

Select Unidad from UnidadMedidas where Estado = 'Activo'

esta consulta me debe de traer las unidades que tengan el estado activo pero no se como implementarlo ya que apenas estoy empezando en asp no se si se hace desde el controlador o desde el modelo y despues como llamarlo en la vista

yo ya levo una parte pero me tira el error de que no puede ser nulo 
no se si la consulta en visual studio no arroja resultado porque en sql si muestra los datos este es el controlador

```
 public class MaterialesController : Controller
 {
    private BDMonlic1Entities db = new BDMonlic1Entities();
    int r;
    // GET: Materiales
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Fruits = PopulateFruits();
        //var materiales = db.Materiales.Include(m => m.UnidadMedidas);
        return View();
        //return View(materiales.ToList());
    }
    private static List<Materiales> PopulateFruits()
    {
        List<Materiales> fruits = new List<Materiales>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "select u.Unidad, u,idunidad from materiales m join UnidadMedidas u on u.IdUnidad=m.IdUnidad where u.Estado = 'Activo'";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        fruits.Add(new Materiales
                        {
                            Estado = sdr["Unidad"].ToString(),
                            IdUnidad = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["idunidad"])});
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return fruits;
    }
```

y esta es la vista donde me deberia llamar los datos de la consulta

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdUnidad, "Unidad *", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">                              
                            @Html.DropDownList("IdUnidad", new SelectList(ViewBag.Fruits, "idunidad", "Unidad"),"Please select", new { @unidad = "Estado" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdUnidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera, no sé si te sirva pero aquí te lo mando, ojo estos son ejemplos:

**PAISES**

```
IEnumerable<Pais> paises()
    {
        List<Pais> temporal = new List<Pais>();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Idpais, NombrePais from tb_paises", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rea.Read())
        {
            Pais p = new Pais();
            p.Idpais = rea.GetString(0);
            p.NombrePais = rea.GetString(1);

            temporal.Add(p);
        }

        rea.Close();

        con.Close();

        return temporal;
    }
```

**AGREGAR [GET]**

```
public ActionResult Agregar() //Esta es la presentación de la pagina
    {
        //Envío a la pagina la lista de los paises
        ViewBag.paises = new SelectList(paises(), "idpais", "nombrepais");

        //Enviar a la pagina un nuevo Cliente
        return View(new Cliente());
    }
```

**AGREGAR [POST]**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Agregar(Cliente c)
        {
        ......................

        ViewBag.paises = new SelectList(paises(), "idpais", "nombrepais", c.idpais); //El 4to parametro sirve que se quede seleccionado el ultimo valor que escogí del DropDown al momento de realizar otro "Create"

        return View(c);
    }
```

**VISTA DEL AGREGAR**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idpais, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idpais", (SelectList)ViewBag.paises)
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Probablemente estés un poco confundido pero te explico, lo que yo hago es crear un método aparte para luego llamarlo y así rellenar los datos. El ActionResult "Agregar" lo que hace es un insert, pero eso no nos interesa, lo que importa es el codigo que esta abajo, en el metodo GET ves que estoy poniendo un viewBag paises, este viewBag lo estoy mandando a la vista con el valor "new SelectList(paises(), "idpais", "nombrepais");", que es una lista en donde el primer parametros vendria a ser el metodo que creamos, luego el segundo seria los valores que se van a mandar y el tercero los valores que se van a mostrar. Cuando lo ejecutes todo estara bien, pero cuando quieres mandar valores a la base de datos en el caso de un registrar, usamos el POST, en el ActionView Agregar [POST] lo que hacemos es poner lo mismo y con un cuarto parametros que seria el valor que se selecciono en el GET, acuerdate que en el GET solo se muestra la vista y en el POST se manda los datos a la base de datos, seria 2 vistas distintas, es por eso que ponemos lo mismo. Y por último ponemos la vista el "@Html.DropDownList("idpais", (SelectList)ViewBag.paises)", este codigo seria el dropdown y el primer parametro seria el id del selectList que estaba en el GET y POST, el segundo parametro seria el ViewBag que estamos pasando a la vista, acuerdate también que los ViewBag sirven para pasar datos desde el controlador a la vista. Y eso seria todo, si tiene preguntas NO DUDES EN CONSULTARME. :)

Comment: Hola es que me sigue tirando todos los id de las medidas no metira los que necesito te muestro

Comment: Uy amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda llevaba 3 días tratando de hacerlo pero ya me dio enserio muchas gracias