# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en un DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy con un proyecto que consta en crear un gestor de contenido para un portal de información, hasta el momento hice el *insert* para agregar nuevos artículos a los foros informativos, ahora sigo con la parte de las consultas para poder realizar los *update* y los *delete*, el problema con las consultas es, que no había manejado antes este el lenguaje ASP.NET con C#.

Necesito saber cómo hacer para que por medio de un `select` o de un `DropDownList` cuando lo despliegue  me muestre los artículos (ids) que están en la base de datos actualmente para así poder  seleccionarlos y que al seleccionarlos me los muestre en unos `TexrArea` y `TextBox`. La información que consulta y que coloco en los `TexrArea` y `TextBox` son una imagen, un título y un párrafo, estoy usando la estructura de capas.

Comment: ¿Usas tecnología MVC o Web Forms o alguna otra en específico?

Comment: Web Forms  Con una estructura de capas

Comment: Es importante añadir las tecnologías que usas actualmente para que puedas obtener las respuestas adecuadas a tu problema planteado. Por esta ocasión he realizado algunas mejoras a tu pregunta para que pueda obtener mayor atención (aunque veo que el problema ha sido resuelto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Una de las soluciones va a ser el siguiente ejemplo:

cargar una lista desplegable en forma de capas:

### En el Código HTML deberías agregar el objeto:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboEjemplo" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboEjemplo_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

### En el Code-Behind se debe agregar el método para cargar por primera vez la lista. Se debe realizar en el Page_Load ya que es cuando se carga la pagina:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            cargarLista();
        }

}
```

### El método `CargarLista()` contiene lo siguiente:

```
public void CargarLista()
{

    IList<coleccionEjemplo> coleccionEjemplo;

        coleccionEjemplo= RepositoryEjemplo.obtener();
        Carga(coleccionEjemplo, cboEjemplo,"Codigo","Nombre");

}
```

**Cabe destacar que el repositorio va a contener la capa de datos y es de donde vas a sacar la información.**

### Por ultimo el método `Carga` es el que va a cargar el datasource del objeto colección hacia la lista desplegable

```
public static void Carga(object coleccion, DropDownList combo, string pDataValueField, string pDataTextField)
{
    try
    {
        combo.Items.Clear();
        combo.DataValueField = pDataValueField;
        combo.DataTextField = pDataTextField;
        combo.DataSource = coleccion;
        combo.DataBind();
        combo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccione Ejemplo", "-1"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

### En el metodo `OnSelectedIndexChanged` debes agregar lo que quieras hacer cuando selecciona un registro. Ejemplo:

```
protected void cboEjemplo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtEjemploNombre.Text = cboEjemplo.SelectedItem.Text; //(el nombre que aparece en pantalla)
    txtEjemploValor.Text = cboEjemplo.SelectedItem.Value; //(el valor que tiene el registro)
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es válida siempre y cuando la solución sea Web Forms, si fuese el caso de MVC o alguna tecnología diferente, pierde sentido

Comment: Me puedes ayudara  entender esta "Cabe destacar que el repositorio va a contener la capa de datos y es de donde vas a sacar la información" muchísimas gracias

Comment: Lo que quise decir con eso es que el método **RepositoryEjemplo.obtener()** va a devolver un objeto que contiene los datos que estas necesitando. En el repositorio es donde se cargan los datos que están en la base de datos.

Comment: Amigo eres el mejor me funciono que me apareciera el titulo que le tengo en la base de datos en el DropDownList, pero no logro que me aparezca lo que tiene ese id en los TextArea y los TextBoxt cuando lo selecciono

Comment: Lo que debes hacer ahí es utilizar es la propiedad `OnSelectedIndexChanged` del `DropDownList` y cuando seleccione uno, ahí vas a saber el valor y el nombre para cargarlos en el textbox y textarea que tengas.

Comment: En serio muchísimas gracias me has ayudado bastante te debo una, debo solo mostrar en un textarea y un texboxt la informacion, en el OnSelectedIndexChanged= coloco el "Page_Load" y en el Page Load especifico los datos ?

Comment: Agregue en la respuesta lo que deberias hacer con el onselectedindexchanged. Por otro lado ademas agregue la propiedad onselectedindexchanged:`<asp:DropDownList ID="cboEjemplo" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboEjemplo_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: protected void ListaArticulo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  asi esta bien

Comment: Correcto, esta bien.

Comment: Eso ahí viene mi pregunta final, dentro de ese protected void debo definir los datos donde quiero que aparezcan ? esa es mi duda que no hayo la manera de mostrar los datos en un textarea del id que ya me muestra el DropDownList

Comment: Correcto, dentro de ese protected void en este caso tenes que definir los datos que quieres que aparezcan (Del registro seleccionado del dropdownlist). Para saber que ítem selecciono la persona se debe utilizar la propiedad del dropdownlist `SelectedItem`(Que la misma contiene toda la información del registro seleccionado) y luego direccionar esa información al textbox (Agregue en la respuesta principal, al final, el ejemplo de como se utiliza)

Comment: Que tal de esta manera **ParrafoArticuloEnterate.InnerText = ListaArticulo.SelectedItem.Text;**  creo que estoy definiendo mal los datos porque en el textarea con el id = ParrafoArticuloEnterate No me aparece nada

Comment: Lo que hace es duplicarme lo que esta en la caja del titulo y si cambio el ListaArticulo no me aparece nada

Comment: Podrías poner el código fuente de como estas declarando **parrafoarticuloenterate.innertext** y los campos que quieras completar? sin esa información se me hace complicado visualizar donde se encuentra el problema que tienes.

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera, no sé si te sirva pero aquí te lo mando, ojo estos son ejemplos:

**PAISES**

```
IEnumerable<Pais> paises()
    {
        List<Pais> temporal = new List<Pais>();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Idpais, NombrePais from tb_paises", con);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rea.Read())
        {
            Pais p = new Pais();
            p.Idpais = rea.GetString(0);
            p.NombrePais = rea.GetString(1);

            temporal.Add(p);
        }

        rea.Close();

        con.Close();

        return temporal;
    }
```

**AGREGAR [GET]**

```
public ActionResult Agregar() //Esta es la presentación de la pagina
    {
        //Envío a la pagina la lista de los paises
        ViewBag.paises = new SelectList(paises(), "idpais", "nombrepais");

        //Enviar a la pagina un nuevo Cliente
        return View(new Cliente());
    }
```

**AGREGAR [POST]**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Agregar(Cliente c)
        {
        ......................

        ViewBag.paises = new SelectList(paises(), "idpais", "nombrepais", c.idpais); //El 4to parametro sirve que se quede seleccionado el ultimo valor que escogí del DropDown al momento de realizar otro "Create"

        return View(c);
    }
```

**VISTA DEL AGREGAR**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idpais, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idpais", (SelectList)ViewBag.paises)
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Probablemente estés un poco confundido pero te explico, lo que yo hago es crear un método aparte para luego llamarlo y así rellenar los datos. El ActionResult "Agregar" lo que hace es un insert, pero eso no nos interesa, lo que importa es el codigo que esta abajo, en el metodo GET ves que estoy poniendo un viewBag paises, este viewBag lo estoy mandando a la vista con el valor "new SelectList(paises(), "idpais", "nombrepais");", que es una lista en donde el primer parametros vendria a ser el metodo que creamos, luego el segundo seria los valores que se van a mandar y el tercero los valores que se van a mostrar. Cuando lo ejecutes todo estara bien, pero cuando quieres mandar valores a la base de datos en el caso de un registrar, usamos el POST, en el ActionView Agregar [POST] lo que hacemos es poner lo mismo y con un cuarto parametros que seria el valor que se selecciono en el GET, acuerdate que en el GET solo se muestra en la "vista" y en el POST se manda los datos a la base de datos, seria 2 vistas distintas, es por eso que ponemos lo mismo. Y por último ponemos la vista el "@Html.DropDownList("idpais", (SelectList)ViewBag.paises)", este codigo seria el dropdown y el primer parametro seria el id del selectList que estaba en el GET y POST, el segundo parametro seria el ViewBag que estamos pasando a la vista, acuerdate también que los ViewBag sirven para pasar datos desde el controlador a la vista. Y eso seria todo, si tienes preguntas NO DUDES EN CONSULTARME. :)

Comment: Esta respuesta es válida siempre y cuando la solución sea MVC, si fuese el caso de Web Forms o alguna tecnología diferente, pierde sentido.

Comment: Cierto, no me he dado cuenta de ese detalle

Comment: Esta respuesta es un [duplicado de esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226139/250) (también tuya). Cuando nos encontramos con respuestas duplicadas, esto se suele deber a uno de estos dos: las preguntas son duplicados (y debería cerrarse una en lugar de responderse) o la respuesta no se ajusta bien a una de las preguntas (es una respuesta parcial o incompleta). Por favor revisa [answer] para más información.

Comment: Amigo muchísimas  gracias La vista del agregar no la entiendo, para poderla aplicar

Comment: 0


Amigo muchas gracias de antemano por tu apoyo muy buen ejemplo, pero la VISTA DEL AGREGAR no entiendo la sintaxis, no hallo donde implementarlo y otra consulta es donde colocaría el "AGREGAR GET" ¿En la capa de acceso a Datos? o ¿en el ASPX.CS del archivo ?

Comment: hola, una pregunta ¿usas tecnología Web Forms, cierto?

Comment: Si señor con estructura de N-Capas